# How to skip null value elements in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The object I am trying to convert to json has a number of attributes but I would like to print attributes with not null values only.

```
{
  "ZIPCODE" : "45869",
  "TYPE2" : null,
  "POSTDIR2" : null,
  "PREDIR" : null,
  "LON" : null,
  "NUMBER" : null,
  "PREDIR2" : null,
  "LAT" : null,
  "POSTDIR" : null,
  "TLID" : null,
  "STREET" : null,
  "STREET2" : null,
  "ZIP" : "45869",
  "LINE2" : null,
  "STATE" : null,
  "ZIPEXTN" : null,
  "CITY" : null,
  "COUNTY" : null,
  "NAME" : null,
  "TYPE" : null
}
```

where I would like only:

```
{
  "ZIPCODE" : "45869",
  "ZIP" : "45869"
}
```

I am trying to use jackson to do this without any success, any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "[Jackson lib](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload#Downloads.2C_2.x)", you can use @JsonInclude

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)
```

or

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

[Read more](http://www.javatutorials.co.in/jackson-ignore-null-empty-values-json-serialization-jsoninclude/)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/) is a good example to read Jason string and iterate through the elements. You can put a null value check before printing the values while iterating them.